# PDO update DATETIME like %TIME

Tags: mysql, wildcard

I am trying to update rows where a datetime type is like time and the date can be different.

pseudo code:
Update where startTime like %time

2019-03-03 10:53:33  (has to be updated)
2019-03-03 12:01:23
2019-03-04 10:53:33  (has to be updated)

```
$startTime = '%10:53:33';

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `table` SET `foo` = '0' WHERE `startTime` LIKE :st ");
$stmt->bindParam(':st', $startTime);
$stmt->execute();
```

*edit: removed strtotime comment*

Is it feasable or should I find another solution? If it is feasible, what would be the approach?

Comment: And what is certainly wrong with the code you posted above? It should work. Did you try to run it? What was the result?

Comment: @YourCommonSense startTime is of the datetime type, thus it will see the content differently than lets say a var char, thats why the code does not work, the value 1551628413 does not contain 10:53:33

Comment: if the field contents is 1551628413 then your field is NOT datetime. Make it datetime, problem solved

Comment: @SLT If `startTime` be datetime, then you're doing the right thing already.  Then, just use `TIME()` to extract and compare the time component.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I tried the code posted above but it did not work, I was wrong to assume the strtotime thing as a result of this and will remove it from the question to make it more clear for others. Tim's code is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `startTime` column is actually a datetime, you should be using the `TIME()` function to extract the time component:

```
$startTime = '10:53:33';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `table` SET `foo` = '0' WHERE TIME(startTime) = :st ");
$stmt->bindParam(':st', $startTime);
$stmt->execute();
```

So, I don't think you need to use `LIKE` here, nor would that be appropriate with a datetime.